# Deny ajax file access using htaccess

Tags: php, jquery, apache, .htaccess

There are some scripts that I use only via ajax and I do not want the user to run these scripts directly from the browser. I use jQuery for making all ajax calls and I keep all of my ajax files in a folder named ajax.

So, I was hoping to create an htaccess file which checks for ajax request (HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH) and deny all other requests in that folder. (I know that http header can be faked but I can not think of a better solution). I tried this:

> ReWriteCond %{HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH} ^$
>   ReWriteCond %{SERVER_URL} ^*/ajax/*.php$
>   ReWriteRule ^.*$ -
>   [F]

But, it is not working. What I am doing wrong? Is there any other way to achieve similar results. (I do not want to check for the header in every script).

Comment: "(I do not want to check for the header in every script)" - could you explain why not? I'd say making a general include file or a seperate class for all your ajax requests would make perfect sense.

Comment: The scripts are already written and they are large in number.

Comment: I seen a similar post on here before, I would question (like I did before) WHY you are trying to limit people accessing the AJAX files directly? What is the concern? Sensitive data that non-logged in users will get? I'm honestly baffled by the reasoning for securing ajax files unless called by javascript.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### The Bad: Apache  :-(

`X-Requested-With` in not a standard [HTTP Header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields).

You can't read it in apache at all (neither by 
`ReWriteCond %{HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH}`
nor by
`%{HTTP:X-Requested-With}`), so its impossible to check it in .htaccess or same place. :-(

### The Ugly: Script :-(

Its just accessible in the script (eg. php), but you said you don't want to include a php file in all of your scripts because of number of files.

### The Good: auto_prepend_file :-)

- But ... there's a simple trick to solve it :-)

`auto_prepend_file` specifies the name of a file that is automatically parsed before the main file. You can use it to include a "checker" script automatically.

So create a `.htaccess` in ajax folder

```
php_value auto_prepend_file check.php
```

and create `check.php` as you want:

```
<?
if( !@$_SERVER["HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH"] ){
        header('HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden');
        exit;
}
?>
```

You can customize it as you want.

Answer (score 18):

I'm assuming you have all your AJAX scripts in a directory ajax, because you refer to ^/ajax/.php$ in your non-working example.

In this folder `/ajax/` place a `.htaccess` file with this content:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase X-Requested-With XMLHttpRequest ajax
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from env=ajax
```

What this does is deny any request without the XMLHttpRequest header.

Answer (score 1):

There are only a few predefined HTTP_* variables mapping to HTTP headers that you can use in a RewriteCond. For any other HTTP headers, you need to use a %{HTTP:header} variable.

Just change

```
ReWriteCond %{HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH} ^$
```

To:

```
ReWriteCond %{HTTP:X-Requested-With} ^$
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check for `if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']=='XMLHttpRequest'){` at the beginning of the document, if it's not set, then don't return anything.

**edit**
Here's why: http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js#L370

**edit 2**
My bad, just read through your post again. You can alternatively make a folder inaccessible to the web and then just have a standard ajax.php file that has `include('./private/scripts.php')` as your server will still be able to access it, but no one will be able to view from their browser.

Comment: I like the idea. However, I have to pass a parameter to the ajax call to distinguish which 'private' script to call. Since the ajax calls are spread in number of files, this is not practical in my particular case.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to using .htaccess is to use the $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] variable to test that the script is being accessed from your page, rather than from another site, etc.