# Deny access to directory with .htaccess

Tags: ajax, .htaccess

I want to protect a directory and the php files in it, from direct web access through an .htaccess file like this:

```
IndexIgnore *
<Files ~ "\.(php)$">
  order allow,deny
  deny from all
</Files>
```

but I want to be able to send ajax requests from a javascript file to those php files an get a result. Is this possible?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466802/deny-ajax-file-access-using-htaccess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only allow POST-requests. Accessing the page from the browser results in an error code, but posting from ajax works. See [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limitexcept).

Note: this qualifies as security through obscurity. If someone looks at your javascript, they'll find out how to get the page results.

Comment: Thank you, that is what I wanted. I don't really care about the security, I just don't want to be directly accessed.