# htaccess mobile redirect with keeping url and ajax call filtering

Tags: php, ajax, .htaccess, redirect

I need an htaccess snippet that let me to redirect the mobile devices to another domain  keeping the url path, but filtering the ajax calls.

example:

www.website.it/project/test => m.website.it/project/test

Comment: the `ajax` calls should be filtered to go to the normal domain, right?

Comment: Yes, the mobile site does ajax calls to the "normal domain"

Comment: are all your ajax files in the same directory? like `domain.com/ajax`? because apache apparently, doesn't like `x_requested_with` headers, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466802/deny-ajax-file-access-using-htaccess

Comment: all my ajax call have this path www.website.com/ajax/...

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
# don't rewrite if file or directory exist
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
# if the above doesn't work, you can try to ignore the directory like this:
# RewriteRule ^ajax - [L,NC] 

# Check accept header for tell-tale signs of mobile devices
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} "text\/vnd\.wap\.wml|application\/vnd\.wap\.xhtml\+xml" [NC,OR]

# Check User Agent for known mobile browsers
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "sony|symbian|nokia|samsung|mobile|windows ce|epoc|opera mini|IEmobile|DoCoMo" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "nitro|j2me|midp-|cldc-|netfront|mot|up\.browser|up\.link|audiovox"[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "blackberry|ericsson,|panasonic|philips|sanyo|sharp|sie-|ipad|ipod|iphone"[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "portalmmm|blazer|avantgo|danger|palm|series60|palmsource|pocketpc"[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "smartphone|rover|ipaq|au-mic,|alcatel|ericy|vodafone\/|wap1\.|wap2\.|mobile safari|android"[NC]

# Rewrite the URL to that of the mobile directory
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://m.website.it/$1 [L,R=302]
```

should detect most mobiles, and the rule at the bottom should redirect everything to your subdomain.

Comment: @keepyourweb I've updated it to check if the file/directory exist, this should work if you're rewriting your urls too and only specific files exist to run ajax

Comment: ok, In this way the ajax calls aren't redirected, but don't work

Comment: @keepyourweb how so? any errors in the console? on the server?

Comment: Because in the php file I check if is really an ajax call and RewriteRule ^ajax - [L,NC] changes the header. So now I use this http://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/