# .htaccess deny from all except jquery

Tags: php, jquery, .htaccess

So I did a fancy interface using CSS and **jQuery**, with a bunch of **PHP** files.

Inside the host, there's a special "_include" folder I made, for all the .php files that are, sometimes requested through **jQuery** and sometimes by **PHP**.

With the **.htaccess** file, I can use the `deny from all` sentence so no one could touch the files manually. Until there, I tested: 
PHP works fine, but the jQuery part doesn't.

I thought then, that .htaccess "denies from all", including jQuery moves.
Is there a way to deny from everything but jQuery requests?

Comment: As far as the server is concerned, there is no difference between an ajax request and a non-ajax request (aside from an unreliable header).

Comment: Put your php files above the document root?

Comment: See [this accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466802/deny-ajax-file-access-using-htaccess) for some information

Comment: And [the neighboring  answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4468729/6263942) too